# SharePoint 2013 list view search box event

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, jquery-events

I need to manually fire the "Enter" press on the search box that's provided by SharePoint 2013 for my document list view.  I've tried to use jQuery .trigger(e) (where e.keyCode == 13) on the id of the search box.  This doesn't do anything.

Is there a manual way to fire this event?